# Show recurring events in the new Event Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

We recently moved to sharepoint online and when i am trying to add the recurring event in calendar i can add it but its not showing up in the event web part.
When i am trying to add the event via event view web part then there is no option for the recurring event option.[image]

Is there any way to add this feature by custom solution??

Answer (score 2):

The Events web part, regardless of the site it's used in, doesn't handle recurrence in either its UI (as you showed in your screenshot) or its end-user display.

I don't think Microsoft believes this is a bug, rather it is the functionality that just isn't supported yet. What Events doesn't really tell you is it's using a SharePoint calendar to store events (go look around your site for a "Events" calendar and you'll find the events are the same).

While the Calendar does support recurrence in its a "Classic" experience but not with the Modern experience.

I suspect that when Microsoft gets around to Modern-izing the Calendar app, it will sort out the lack of support for Recurrence in Events web part.

Comment: Hi @AIM4DREAM, does this answers you question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others with similar question in future. Also, the question will be removed from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, this is something that they [do not plan to implement](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/20296774-show-recurring-events-in-the-new-event-web-part) for some reason; they instead point people to use their Group Calendars.

This isn't a perfect solution, but [there is a workaround we found online](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Recreating-Recurring-Sharepoint-Calendar-Events/m-p/260185#M26269) that we're using at our organization. Essentially, it involves using Flow to script creating "standalone" events in the SharePoint Events calendar with the year incremented by one - this can be modified as needed of course.

Hope this helps.