# SharePoint Modern Events Web part does not display recurring events from calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages, recurring-events

I am using modern SharePoint page. I have one calendar list with recurring events. When I add the Events web part in the modern page, it does not display the recurring events.

Can any one help on this please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior of SharePoint online Events web part.

Events web part doesn't show recurring events and you can't add a recurrence when adding an event from the Events Web Part.

For more information, read my answer given at: [Show recurring events in the new Event Web Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252932/show-recurring-events-in-the-new-event-web-part/252975#252975)

Also, Microsoft has stated that there are no current plans to add this functionality, as you can display recurring events in the Group Calendar web part (which is totally different than events web part).

**Source**: [Recurring Events](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/20472028-recurring-events) - You can vote on this idea to support it.

**Additional Reference**:

1. [Modern Page Events Web Part missing reoccurring events](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/modern-page-events-web-part-missing-reoccurring-events/m-p/207009)