# Showing a calendar as a group calendar instead of events web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, calendar, modern-experience, recurring-events

I at first wanted to show a calendar list with recurring events as a web part on my SharePoint page. But when I selected the calendar, it just showed 'No upcoming events' and a default 'Title of event' and 'Month 01'. From what I understood in [previous questions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287153/sharepoint-modern-events-web-part-does-not-display-recurring-events-from-calenda), recurring events are still not supported by Microsoft.

I sort of found a workaround by selecting 'This site' (instead of 'Events list on this site') and entering a category from that calendar. However, aside from just showing events from that one category, it also lists all the events from that calendar rather than upcoming events specifically.

I read that the solution is to use the Group calendar web part. But the group calendar only lets me select an O365 group, whereas my calendar is not in a group but on the main SharePoint site.

How can I show my calendar as a Group calendar web part in this case? I'm guessing I need to move it to a private group?

Answer (score 0):

As you already know:

1. Events web part does **not** support recurring events
2. The Group calendar web part only allows you to put a **Microsoft 365 group calendar**. So, this web part works only on **Team** sites.

So, you cannot show the events stored in SharePoint (calendar/events) list in Group calendar web part.

---

Also, there are custom (SPFx) calendar web parts developed by community members. You can check those using below links. You can download them & use as it is if they fulfil your requirements or you can enhance them as you want:

1. [Calendar Feed](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-calendar-feed)
2. [Calendar](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-calendar)
3. [Modern Calendar](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/js-modern-calendar)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there an effective way of copying/moving my calendar from the main Sharepoint site to a team site (so that I could use the group calendar web part) without recreating the calendar from scratch?